# Is 'setImageURI' a good method to show a photo in an ImageView?

Tags: android, imageview, sharedpreferences, uri

I want to show in an ImageView a photo that I already saved its path to SharedPrefManager (a Shared Preferences class that I created).
I am retrieving the image path correctly from my class SharedPrefManager, but the 'setImageUri' method is not working.
When I call the method, the app crashes.
Is there any way to solve it?

```
Uri selectImage;

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO) {
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            selectImage = data.getData();

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                assert selectImage != null;
                inputStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectImage);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            saveIt(selectImage);
            imageView.setImageURI(selectImage);
        }
    }

}
private void saveIt(Uri uri) {
 SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
    .saveImage(String.valueOf(uri));
}

public void showImage(){
    String mImageUri = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getContext()).getImage();
    savedImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(mImageUri));
}
```

This is my Java code (above) that I used in the fragment to capture, save and show the photo.

```
 public boolean saveImage(String imageURI) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.putString(KEY_IMAGE,imageURI);

    editor.commit();
    return true;
}
```

This is the code to save the image path in SharedPrefManager

Comment: Could you add the error message

Comment: No error is shown, the app crashes. @Narendra_Nath

Comment: go to the logcat and check . there has to be an error log

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html

Comment: E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@6dc1c32 
That's what I got

Comment: Who or what is trying to read lines from which file? Reading lines from an imge? Which file does not exist? Which statement in your code does cause this?

Comment: The image is shown when I am still in the same activity
But when I force close the app and reopen it, and then I press on show Image button, the path is the same (in debug) but the image view is not filled with the image , so the app crashes
That is my problem and what I am asking about

Comment: If the app crashes then you are not catching an exception that is thrown. Catch that exception to begin with. And... you did not read the link CommansWare did provide you? You should know by now why that what you want does not work. Also you should now by now the solution and small changes you have to make to your code.